# Cython w/ STL vector & no NumPy to call from other apps, what's missing?

Tags: c++, numpy, dll, stl, cython

I have Cython code that I'm trying to compile as a DLL so that I can call it from other languages.  The strange thing is that using STL vectors instead of NumPy `MemoryViews` I get 12x lower performance.  Trying to use OpenMP with Cython's `prange` also doesn't seem to work (I get 100% utilization on all 4 threads w/ memoryviews and maybe 50% max w/ STL vectors).  Anyone have any thoughts on how to revamp the STL version to be comparable?  The Cython profiler only shows the `cimport cython` and `cpdef` statements to interact with Python... could it be that when called from C++ just renaming them as `cdef` would improve things?  Or do I have to use Intel MKL vectors as in the examples here https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/531898 which with simple option formulas these are really not a big deal to rewrite...?  I'm really so inexperienced in C++ I would have to research on the internet to just create a C++ only test script... Code segment below:

```
cimport cython
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double)
    double sqrt(double)
    double log(double)
    double erf(double)

cdef inline double std_norm_cdf(double x):
    return 0.5*(1+erf(x/sqrt(2.0)))

cpdef CyBlackP(vector[double] Black_PnL, vector[double] Black_S, vector[double] Black_Texpiry, vector[double] Black_strike, vector[double] Black_volatility, vector[double] Black_IR, vector[int] Black_callput):
    cdef int i, N
    N = Black_PnL.size() 
    cdef double d1, d2

    for i in range(N):
        d1 = (log(Black_S[i] / Black_strike[i]) + Black_Texpiry[i] * (Black_volatility[i] *Black_volatility[i]) / 2) / (Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i]))
        d2 = d1 - Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i])
        Black_PnL[i] = exp(-Black_IR[i] * Black_Texpiry[i]) * (Black_callput[i] * Black_S[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d1) - Black_callput[i] * Black_strike[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d2)) 

    return Black_PnL
```

For others out there this code above is tied out completely to be accurate w/ the Black model if you want to use it.

Comment: How are you calling this? (i.e. this version, not the numpy one)

Comment: Just as a side note, it should be possible to import function definitions like `from libc.math cimport exp, sqrt, log, erf`

Comment: @chrisb I haven't called it from C++ yet was just trying from Python for the timings with NumPy arrays:  Black_PnL = np.zeros(10000000)
Black_S=np.random.randint(200, 10000, 10000000)*0.01
Black_volatility=np.random.rand(10000000)*1.2
Black_Texpiry=np.abs(np.random.randint(1,500,10000000)*0.01)
Black_strike=np.random.uniform(0,2,10000000)*Black_S
Black_IR=np.random.rand(10000000)*0.1
Black_callput=np.sign(np.random.randn(10000000))
Black_callput=Black_callput.astype(np.int)
%timeit CyBlackP(Black_PnL,Black_S,Black_Texpiry, Black_strike, Black_volatility, Black_IR, Black_callput)

Comment: Yes @J.J.Hakala that works for sure (just tried), still confused about the slow performance but maybe I need to write a small C++ program to call it with `cdef` to realize any performance gains... My C++ is not good even a simple hint on how to assign constant inputs to a vector for each input variable would help me out, i.e. test vectors copy / pasted into constant vectors I generate through NumPy.

Comment: You could test performance with different [cython compiler directives](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html) like `@cython.cdivision(True)` and `@cython.boundscheck(False)`.  Declaring `cdef size_t i, N` may also affect the performance a little bit.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala yes that's what my actual compiled program has before each statement: 
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is slow because numpy arrays and c++ vectors are not interchangeable - based on the doc note [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library) it seems like the numpy array is being iterated/copied into a new vector.

For example, consider a couple functions that do nothing:

```
# ext.pyx
cpdef pass_vec(vector[double] v):
    return 0.0

cpdef pass_arr(double[::1] a):
    return 0.0
```

The timings below highlight just how much overhead there is.  Note that your function will be fast if called with a c++ vector as the argument, just not with a numpy array passed.

```
In [1]: import ext

In [2]: a = np.zeros(1000000)

In [4]: %timeit ext.pass_arr(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 808 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit ext.pass_vec(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 63 ms per loop
```

Comment: Okay just saw that your answer contains the `ext.pyx` function, trying to pass something comparable to what I have but a little confused on the above timings since 1 does 1M and the other does 10 loops... I see 63ms = 63M ns so attempting to figure out how I'd pass the C++ vector to the function instead of passing a NumPy array. As from what I understand the much faster `pass_arr` function is using a `MemoryView` and the other is not, yet your answer implies that passing a C++ vector would be fast but I don't see the function call supporting it???  Do you have a `pass_vec` illustration?

Comment: `timeit` reports the timing per-loop, it just runs more loops if something is fast.  To pass a c++ vector, you'd have to call the function from c++, any python type is going to have to go through some kind of layer of conversion.

Comment: @chrisb What does it means  10 loops or 100000 loops in %timeit output

Comment: It is the output from the IPython timeit magic - it runs a diff # of times depending on how fast a function is, but times reported are always per call. http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit